# Can we use phone's UUID/MAC to authenticate the user? Should I use Google Playstore system, which also offers ranking?

Tags: android

I'm developing a pay for win Android app, in which users are, among others, ranked according to the amount they have spent. The payments are Android in-app purchases.

My questions are:

1. Is an authentication system required for my users, in order to purchase and be ranked? In other words: instead of using an authentication system, could I use the UUID of the phone, or its MAC address, or any other piece of information that would actually act as an authentication system? If yes: why isn't there any other Android app that proceed in this way (indeed, they use Facebook/Google authentication, or e-mail + password authentication, etc.)?
2. Is there any Java ranking library that I could use and bind it to the Android in-app purchases? In particular: does Google offer such an API?
3. Is it a good idea to use Google's authentication and ranking based on Google Play? The ranking criteria must also be the total spent amounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Authentication and authorization

Firstly, I would like to make the distinction between authentication and authorization.

Authentication is a way to determine a user apart from other users.  Authentication allows a developer to identify Jane Doe as a separate entity from all other users. Authentication is often a precursor to authorization.

Authorization pertains to what actions a user can take on particular resources.  Authorization deals with the *what, when, how* as opposed to the authentication that deals with *who*.

To state your questions using more definitive language you are asking for best practices relating to:

1. Authenticating a user inside an application that is available on the Google Play Store, and
2. Calculating totals related to Android's In-App purchasing, and
3. Authorizating a user to take a *claim* action on a *prize* entity depending on the aforementioned total aggregate

## Recommendations

I would highly suggest you use **Google's OAuth 2.0** service to authenticate users as opposed to building your own authentication framework or implementing any other authentication framework, especially if this application is only used within th Android ecosystem.  I recommend this because:

1. Android users already have a Google account, and
2. Implementing your own authentication framework requires very niche skills which usually require a team of people, and
3. Google already offers an **Subscription and In-App Purchasing API** which can be queried to rank you users, and
4. You will already have implemented this API to support in app purchasing to begin with

I would highly suggest you do not use MAC address or UUID authentication because

1. On a rooted phone I can change my MAC address, and
2. It does not uniquely identify a user across multiple devices, and
3. Using this type of authentication would not provide any benefit to your second goal of authorizing actions based on a total aggregate

In other words by using Google's authentication mechanism you can not only uniquely identify users across multiple devices, but you can also leverage the in app payment system to build your particular authorization logic.

The **In-App Purchasing API** already contains the necessary information you want since you will need to implement it to support in app purchasing to begin with.  You might as well use it as a basis for ranking since it is readily available, secure, and contains the information you need with well documented ways of accessing it.

Additionally, you may want to look at the promotional capabilities and *one time product-specific billing features* functions and related APIs. This might fit your use case and it may make your application more secure and standardized.

Using the provided authentication framework and in app purchasing capabilities standardizes your application up until you implement the *claim your prize* functionality. People enjoy standardization because they become familiarized with it, and it provided a level of trust, so I would definitely investigate the other aforementioned APIs to see if your prize idea can be based off a foundation provided by Android.  This would standardize your app all the way through and, in my opinion, would be best practice.

## Summary

I would provide some sample code but your questions are still a but *high level* to provide anything useful in the way of code snippets. To summarize though my recommendations are as follows

1. Leverage the **Google OAuth 2.0** framework for authentication, and
2. Leverage the **In-App purchasing API** and related APIs as a way to calculate total and rank users, and
3. Investigate the **promotional** capabilities, or **one time product-specific features** already provided by Google to see if it fits your use case, and
4. Avoid using MAC addresses and UUIDs for authentication for the reasons I outlined above

## Edit ....

After rereading your title I realized I glossed over the fact that, as I understand it, the term **ranking** and it's related functionality as used by Android is mostly centered around where you application sits, popularity wise, in comparison to other applications. I have not seen the term used by Android to refer to internal ranking of users against some developer-defined criteria ( total, in your case ).

I'm not saying it does not exist, just that every time I see ranking it refers to application popularity. Therefore I would refrain from using that as a query term when researching how to build this application as you will likely get a plethora of false positives.

What I think you want, to reiterate, is

1. Authentication
2. Calculating in app purchasing totals
3. Promotional or one time features based on that total

Those terms will suite you much better.  Please feel free to start a new post when you get further in to the project if you need assistance consuming the APIs

Comment: Just a little remark: "Google's OAuth 2.0" ---> you can set up your own system, or use the Google Android Sign-in API (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/)